# Chef Elementory OS (Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[apache2]')

Tags: chef-infra, devops

```
 * package[tree] action install[2020-02-18T15:27:02+05:30] INFO: Processing package[tree] action install (starter::default line 8)


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[tree]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::ProviderNotFound
    ----------------------------------
    Cannot find a provider for package[tree] on elementary version 5.1.2

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /home/mrunknown/Downloads/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/starter/recipes/default.rb

      8: package "tree"
      9: 

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /home/mrunknown/Downloads/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/starter/recipes/default.rb:8:in `from_file'
```

Code:

```
package("tree") do
  package_name "tree"
  action [:install]
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  declared_type :package
  cookbook_name "starter"
  recipe_name "default"
end
```

System Info:

```
chef_version=15.7.32
platform=elementary
platform_version=5.1.2
ruby=ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef-workstation/bin/chef-client
```

Comment: i can't install any packages using chef but on my machine i can install this packages,why chef is giving problem please help

Comment: chef has just no idea what package provider Elementary use. From a quick search it seems to be apt based, so you'll need to replace `package` by [`apt_package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_apt_package.html)

Comment: The package resource choose which provider to user based on the platform_family, you can check how chef see you system with ` ohai platform_family` and open a pull request to add it into https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/platform.rb

Comment: apt_package is also not working

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the solution for this question ,refer this link https://docs.chef.io/resource_gem_package.html

it uses gem_package

Comment: gem_package is for ruby gems. I doubt you install a ruby gem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search shows that Elementary OS uses `apt`, so you definitely need to use `apt_package`.

```
apt_package 'tree' do
  action :install
end
```

But you said it didn't work for you. I guess you encountered some *apt* error that said that it couldn't find a candidate for package *tree*. That was because you needed to run `apt update` before installing packages. You can do this by prepending your package resource with `apt_update` resource.

```
apt_update 'update' do
  action :update
end

apt_package 'tree' do
  action :install
end
```

Comment: as you said i updated but apt_package still not working,

Comment: Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[vim]'

Comment: Can you update your question with this new info and please provide all the error message.